# Which laptop tools does Ubuntu come with?

Tags: 11.04, hardware, laptop

Which tools for managing laptop-specific tasks are installed by default on Ubuntu (say, 11.04)?

Thinking about the following might be useful to get you started in answering: Is it ACPI that monitors the battery? Which tool controls sleep and hibernation? Which tool enables CPU frequency scaling? Is laptop mode tools installed? Powermoded?

More info about laptop tools: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Laptop

Comment: The stackexchange system works best when the questions are split up. Please ask one question per post. Thank you. :)

Comment: The first question is "the" question. The other are hints towards what the readers should be thinking about. I'll edit my post to make this more clear. The reason that splitting up would be a bad idea is because often these tools overlap and intersect, and furthermore, I don't have a complete list of "laptop specific" tools at my disposal to ask separate questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Natty [laptop packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=laptop&searchon=names&suite=natty&section=all)